# Efficient way to swap array elements that are flipped

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

Suppose you have an array of points that have a chance to be flipped symmetrically (shown below)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Data
a = np.array([0.1,-0.325,-0.55,0.775,1])  # x-axis
b = np.array([10,-3.077,-1.818,1.2903,1]) # y-axis
c = np.array([-0.1,0.325,0.55,-0.775,-1]) # x-axis
d = np.array([-10,3.077,1.818,-1.2903,-1])# y-axis
    
y = [a,b,c,d] # The array is created this way intentionally for when I apply it to my case
    
plt.plot(y[0],y[1],'k.')
plt.plot(y[2],y[3],'r.')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with data-points that are flipped symmetrically.]

How do I automatically check each array elements and write a condition that corrects the position of these points, assuming that we know what form it is supposed to have?

edit:

This is the graph I am trying to get

[image: Corrected Graph]

Comment: What exactly do you know?

Comment: I "know" that the points are supposed to be flipped such that the red and black dots follow their own trends. edit: For the case I am trying to solve, I have a program that will give me solutions but not necessarily in the correct order, so I have to figure out how to correct the array after solutions are found.

Comment: maybe you should create one list with pairs `(x,y)` and split it into two list - first with `y < 0` and second with `y > 0` (or first with `x < 0` and second with `x > 0`). Or maybe you should run function which check values in `b` and change all to `abs(y)`, and second function which check `d` and change all to `-abs(y)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you actually gave me an idea that I think solved my problem. Is it good practice for me to post my solution if I figure it out before someone comments an answer? Or should I delete my question?

Comment: if you resolve problem then you can send it as answer, next you can mark it as accepted, and probably few minut later you can upvote it. This way you can get more points (reputation score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example will work

```
a = np.absolute(a)
b = np.absolute(b)
c = -np.absolute(c)
d = -np.absolute(d)
```

but other situations may need `minus` for different lists. So it can be bigg problem to recognize which list need minus.

Better can be to create pairs `(x,y)` and split them to two list by `x > 0` `x < 0` (or `y > 0` `y < 0`) and later convert pairs back to lists `x` and `y`

(maybe with numpy you could do it easier and faster)

```
all_pairs = list(zip(a,b)) + list(zip(c,d))

# ---

lower = []
higher = []
for pair in all_pairs:
    if pair[0] > 0:
        higher.append(pair)
    else:
        lower.append(pair)

# ---

a, b = list(zip(*higher))
c, d = list(zip(*lower))
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
a = np.array([0.1,-0.325,-0.55,0.775,1])  # x-axis
b = np.array([10,-3.077,-1.818,1.2903,1]) # y-axis
c = np.array([-0.1,0.325,0.55,-0.775,-1]) # x-axis
d = np.array([-10,3.077,1.818,-1.2903,-1])# y-axis

all_pairs = list(zip(a,b)) + list(zip(c,d))
print(all_pairs)

higher = []
lower = []
for pair in all_pairs:
    if pair[0] > 0:
        higher.append(pair)
    else:
        lower.append(pair)
        
print(higher)
print(lower)

a, b = list(zip(*higher))
c, d = list(zip(*lower))
    
y = [a,b,c,d] # The array is created this way intentionally for when I apply it to my case
    
#plt.plot(y[0],y[1],'k.')
#plt.plot(y[2],y[3],'r.')

plt.plot(*y[0:2], 'k.')
plt.plot(*y[2:4], 'r.')

plt.show()
```